# php curl v python request send file

Tags: php, python, curl, request

I am trying to send a file with php curl, trying to replicate the following  python request:

```py
requests.post( f'{url}/sample', data={"forced": True}, files={'sample': open(filepath, 'rb')}, verify=verify_ssl )
```

Below is my attempt to do the same request using php curl, I however always get an error 400, 'missing sample':

```php
$post = array(
    'files'=>array(
        'sample'=> file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),
    ),
    'data'=>array(
        'forced'=>TRUE,
    ),
);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url.'/sample');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Skip SSL Verification
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Python request appears to be `multipart/form-data` and not a JSON request like the PHP example.

To upload a file with curl, see the [`CURLFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php) class.

I think it should look like this:

```
<?php

$sample = new \CURLFile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$post = [
    'forced' => true,
    'sample' => $sample,
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url.'/sample');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works great if I remove the 'forced' parameter, ie : $post = ['sample' =>$sample'] as I'm getting 'Unknown parameter 'Forced' but this is an optional parameter anyway.

Comment: Glad it worked! The `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` in this case can be a mix of files and regular post vars, unlike with requests where you have different keys like `data` or `files`. Things worth noting are, if you pass an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, it will use `multipart/form-data`, a string will be assumed to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data unless you explicitly set a Content-Type request header. You can use something like `$post = http_build_query($postArray);` for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS when you have an array that should be a url-encoded POST (not json or multipart).

Comment: I have another issue this time with a GET request, this is what the python command looks like : 

requests.get( f'{url}/report', data={'token': reporting_token, 'format': 'pdf'} )

Trying to do the same thing in curl :
$ch = curl_init();

$params = array(
 'token'=>'abcdefgh',
 'format'=>'pdf',
)

$url = $url.'&'.http_build_query($params);  //this shows http://xxx/report?token=abcdefgh&format=pdf
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

This couldn't be any simpler, however I am getting the following error : {"message":"missing parameter : token"}

Comment: Try `$url.'?'.http_build_query($params);` instead of `$url.'&'.http_build_query($params);`

Comment: no sorry that was actually a misprint I found a fix I posted it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792670/php-curl-vs-python-get-request/58797995#58797995