# php curl vs python GET request

Tags: php, python, get, request

I have an issue trying to convert a python GET request to php curl. 
This is what the python command looks like :

```
requests.get( f'{url}/report', data={'token': reporting_token, 'format': 'pdf'} )
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in php curl :

```
$ch = curl_init();

$params = array(
    'token'=>'abcdefgh',
    'format'=>'pdf',
)

$url = $url.'?'.http_build_query($params);      //this shows http://xxx/report?token=abcdefgh&format=pdf
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This couldn't be any simpler, however I am getting the following error :

```
{"message":"missing parameter : token"}
```

Comment: The query string is seperated by a `?`. You url will only be valid if it has an argument already.

Comment: sorry misprint, I changed it, the issue is elsewhere..

Comment: @Arbiz: `data=` is not `?token=`. Are your sure you don't need `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the header, I did try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); but that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

OK here's the fix for anyone interested, the idea is to produce the curl command:
curl -GET -d 'token=abcdefg'

This can be achieved in php curl forcing a GET providing post fields...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $get);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```